# Alfresco javascript search insensitive case

Tags: javascript, search, whitespace, alfresco, case-sensitive

I'm using search root objet to perform search

`var result = search.query({query: "TYPE:\"cm:category\"  AND @cm\\:name:CAt*"  })`.

What i want to do exactly is to select categories which name begin with the term "cat" (but ignoring case)

How can i do that?

I want also the query  ignore whitespace before and after category name.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could simply use this Query

```
var result = search.query({query: "TYPE:\"cm:category\"  AND @cm\\:name:*CAt*"  })
```

It should give you all categories whose name contains "cat" word. 
You can also try with other wildcard character "?" in your query.

Only thing to remember is "For tokenized fields the pattern match can not be exact as all the non token characters (whitespace, punctuation, etc) will have been lost and treated as equal."

Comment: Hi Mitpatoliya,

If i understand i must change sol4 (or lucene ) query analyser before reindexing repository item. because with my actual configuration search is case sensitive.  Im i right ? 

I m using alfresco 5.0.d version. Where and how can i choose the correct analyser for french language  ?